# How to parsing mysql table to make parenting and child in Node.JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to make response parenting and child in Node.JS from this mysql table. [image: mysql_table]

My problem is how to parsing the table? I want to get result like this code:

```
{  
       "comment":[  
          {  
             "replies":[  
                {  
                   "id":97,
                   "name":"myfirst",
                   "text":"Sub Commentar user 46"
                },
                {  
                   "id":96,
                   "name":"myfirst2",
                   "text":"Sub Commentar user 46"
                }
             ],
             "id":95,
             "name":"tes123",
             "text":"Comment text Parent 46"
          },
          {  
             "replies":[  
                {  
                   "id":99,
                   "name":"myfirst2",
                   "text":"Sub Commentar user 48"
                }
             ],
             "id":98,
             "name":"tes123",
             "text":"Comment text Parent 48"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query and table. Just i don't know how to parse the table while looping. Can you help me?

Comment: Then you should show us the query and what are the results you get (and how you tried to parse them if you have any code so far)